# django: redirecting back to a multimodel view after passing required variables

Tags: django, redirect

I'm receiving the error:

Reverse for 'botanyoverview' with arguments '({'flotation_id': '21', 'sample_id': '28780488'},)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['botany/botanyoverview/flotation/(?P[0-9]+)/sample/(?P[0-9]+)$']

Both ids exist, usually this is an issue in the urls.py but I can't seem to spot it.

What I have are several tables/models which are displayed in one html view, you click on one and you go to the edit page, I'm trying to fix the redirect so it returns you to the beginning overview page, this requires the flotation and sample ids. The url works originally but throws this error when trying to redirect back to the original page after editing. I can't see the error, any ideas?

views.py

```
def editplantpart(request, pk, fk='', sp='', fl=''):
        post = get_object_or_404(PlantPart, pk=pk)
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = PlantPartForm(request.POST, instance=post)
            if form.is_valid():
                post = form.save(commit=False)
                sample_id=sp
                flotation_id=fl
                post.save()
                return redirect('botanyoverview', {  'flotation_id': flotation_id, 'sample_id':sample_id,})

        else:
            form = PlantPartForm(instance=post)
        return render(request, 'plantpart/create_plantpart.html', {'form': form})
```

urls.py

```
re_path('flotation/(?P<fl>\d+)/sample/(?P<sp>\d+)/fraction/(?P<fk>\d+)/plantpart/edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/', views.editplantpart, name='editplantpart'),
```

html

```
<tr class='clickable-row' data-href="{% url 'editplantpart' fk=plantpart.fraction_id pk=plantpart.plantpart_id fl=flotation.flotation_id sp=flotation.sample_id  %}">
```

@@@ edit

url for botany overview

```
path('botanyoverview/flotation/<int:flotation_id>/sample/<int:sample_id>', views.botanyoverview, name='botanyoverview'),
```

Comment: Show the url for `botanyoverview`.

Comment: url added to the above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `redirect` by passing the name of a view and optionally some positional or **keyword**(in your case) arguments; the URL will be reverse resolved using the `reverse()` method:

```
redirect('botanyoverview', flotation_id=flotation_id, sample_id=sample_id)
```

Here are some redirect examples:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#examples